# Angular Service dont stores boolean

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have an angular Service:

```
presence.service('AuthService', function($http, PresenceURLService){
    var apiURL = PresenceURLService.apiURL;
    this.isLogged = false,
    this.access_token = "",
    this.login = function(credentials, callback){
        var configura = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        };
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url: apiURL+'login',
            data: credentials,
            config: configura
        }).then(function(response){
            //success
            this.isLogged = response.data.response;
            this.access_token = response.data.access_token;
            callback(response.data);
        }, function(response){
            //error
            callback(response.data);
        });
    }
});
```

Whenever an user tries to login, the API returns tru or false and it is stored in `this.isLogged`. Works fine.

I have this code on run for the app, in order to stop the state load if the user is not logged:

```
presence.run(function($rootScope, $location, $state, AuthService) {


    $rootScope.$on( '$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState  , toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        var isLogin = toState.name === "login";
        if(isLogin){
           return; // no need to redirect 
        }
        console.log("State we are going to: "+toState.name);

        // now, redirect only not authenticated

        var logged = AuthService.isLogged;
        console.log("Before load must check the AuthService isLogged var: "+logged);

        if(logged === false) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stop current execution
            $state.go('login'); // go to login
        }
    });
});
```

In this code logged is always false. But, previously, when I call login() function, it is stored true.

Why it losses the data and how to obtain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because context in which you set `isLogged` is not `AuthService`. Read more [here how `this` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/2509344)

Try this instead:

```
presence.service('AuthService', function($http, PresenceURLService){
    var that = this; // In order to access correct context within callback
    var apiURL = PresenceURLService.apiURL;
    this.isLogged = false,
    this.access_token = "",
    this.login = function(credentials, callback){
        var configura = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        };
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url: apiURL+'login',
            data: credentials,
            config: configura
        }).then(function(response){
            //success
            // Use that instead of this here. As this doesn't refers to AuthService
            that.isLogged = response.data.response;
            that.access_token = response.data.access_token;
            callback(response.data);
        }, function(response){
            //error
            callback(response.data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: First time I hear about this. Maybe I am a total nob ^^. It works perfect. Obviously this inside $http is related to $http function, not to AuthService. Thanks a lot, you healed my headache ^^

Comment: If that solved your problem. Don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Have to wait 3 minutes :P